# Installing QGIS Plugin with Python code

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, installation

Is it possible to install QGIS Plugins with Python code?

I would like to be able to provide users who have a basic QGIS image served up to them, to be able to quickly install all their required plugins with a tailored Python script to save them manually installing each via the usual menu route, one at a time.

I cannot see any code that runs in logs after a successful plugin install and no clues online in my searches.

Comment: you could just unpack a zip file in the packages folder

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, there is no access to the install area as a user so cannot refer to specific locations that would typically be on a C drive. Does that make sense. Installing with QGIS via the usual route is fine, but I don't have access to do things like that unfortunately. I was hoping I might be able to have the users run their own little Python snippet to set up favourites (done) and add Plugins in one quick hit.

Comment: I guess there are several ways to do this. If you want to install public plugins (registered in the QGIS plugin repo), then you could use the `pyplugin_installer` instance. Quick example: `import pyplugin_installer` | `pyplugin_installer.instance().fetchAvailablePlugins(False)` | `pyplugin_installer.instance().installPlugin('asistente_ladm_col')`  You can [read the installer.py code to get some inspiration](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/a8de679601be931bd356a69f4b1cbb224581339d/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py).

Comment: Thank you Germán - that is exactly what I needed,

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll elaborate more for answering this question, as it can be the reference for other people searching how to install a plugin via Python. I'll cover more cases.

Comment: That would be great Germán.
I notice some inconsistency in results, mixed success for some plugins over others, and not sure if it is the way I am calling (parameter) the last line of code, or if it is running subsequent times - not dug deeper yet. For example, you refer to the example plugin with lowercase and spaces replaced with '_' , which I have tried to do for 'Profile Tool' but with the following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\pyplugin_installer\installer.py", line 289, in installPlugin
    plugin = plugins.all()[key]
KeyError: 'profile_tool'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is yes.

## Installing a plugin from the QGIS Plugins Repository

This is how you can install a plugin called `loadthemall`:

```
import pyplugin_installer
pyplugin_installer.instance().fetchAvailablePlugins(False)
pyplugin_installer.instance().installPlugin('loadthemall')
```

Plugin keys correspond to their folder names. Some examples: `AppendFeaturesToLayer`, `asistente_ladm_col`, `loadthemall`, `profiletool`.

As last resort, you could get plugin keys in this way (if you haven't called `fetchAvailablePlugins`, it will give you installed plugin keys):

```
pyplugin_installer.installer_data.plugins.all().keys()
```

## Installing a plugin from ZIP file

```
pyplugin_installer.instance().installFromZipFile('/path/to/plugin/file.zip')
```

## Uninstalling a plugin

```
pyplugin_installer.instance().uninstallPlugin('loadthemall')
```

---

*Note: This is not a stable API, and might be modified with no backwards compatibility.*

Comment: This fully solves my issues, and this in particular has helped with the issue of how to call the individual Plugins:

pyplugin_installer.installer_data.plugins.all().keys()

Comment: What does this line do?
pyplugin_installer.instance().fetchAvailablePlugins(False)

Comment: It goes to internet and fetches data of plugins that QGIS hasn't fetched yet. If you have other repos configured, it will visit those repos as well. See the [source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/a8de679601be931bd356a69f4b1cbb224581339d/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py#L109) for details.